Nautilus : OpenJDK Java 21 missing from "Open With"
I have upgraded from 23.10 to 24.04 today
In nautilus I tried to run a java jar-file. But I couldn't, because in the "open with - list" there is no choice "OpenJDK..."
I had a look into /usr/share/applications/openjdk-21-java.desktop and compared it with the older version openjdk-17-java.desktop.
I can't see any differences. Except the version number.
I can run the jar-file in a terminal, but it is combersome.
What can I do. Any ideas ?
